# PHP connection_aborted() does not work when page changes

Tags: php

I'm trying to serve an image while adding a MySQL row for each second the image was viewed.

I'm serving it in chunks of 1024 bits (total size is of image is 20kb)

The problem is that if I load the page where the image is displayed and then close the window or click a link that takes me to a different page the script keeps running and does not `die` as it should.

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
$file = 'a.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
mysql_select_db("mydb",$conn);

$fp=fopen($file,"rb");
$i=0;

while (!feof($fp)) {

    print(fread($fp,1024));
    sleep(1);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (VIEWTIME) VALUES ('$i')");
    $i++;
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    if (connection_aborted()) {
        die();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to find a 'server-side' only solution since I have some technical restrictions that prevents me from using any JS or any client side languages.

Comment: You should probably take the connection (mysql_connect/mysql_select_db) out of the loop for better performance. As for the question, you can probably do it with AJAX, I'm not sure it's possible without some kind of client-side check.

Comment: A20k file will have loaded before the server can blink. Try with a 20mb file!

Comment: Hey @Ynhockey thanks for your comment, I want to keep this server-side only due to some technical restrictions.

Comment: @TobyAllen I'm reading it in chunks of 1024bits and ``sleeping`` for a second between each chunk

Comment: @TobyAllen You're right I should definitely change that.. My current main concern is how to abort the script when the user goes to a different page

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
ignore_user_abort(false);
```

Should be

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

[Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)